# D'Alembert's solution and Heaviside function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Starting with the wave equation $$u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx}$$

and given the initial conditions

$$u(x,0) = \phi(x)\\
u_t(x, t) = \psi(x)\\
-\infty<x<\infty
$$

We can derive D'Alembert's solution

$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\phi(x - ct) + \phi(x + ct) \right] + \frac{1}{2c}\int_{x - ct}^{x + ct}\psi(s)ds$$

I have two questions;

a) Use D'Alembert's solution in $x > 0$ with $u_x(0,t) = 0$ for all $t > 0$ with the initial conditions

$$u(x,0) = 0\\
u_t(x, t) = \hat{\psi}(x)\\
0<x<\infty
$$

Here, I think we take the even extension of $\hat{\psi}(x)$ and use that to find a solution of the problem for $-\infty < x < \infty$ and then just limit to $x > 0$.

Edit: This is what I used to answer this question. I just need some clarification that this is the correct idea for some piece of mind, and in order to progress to the next question, which is the one I am truely stuck on.

b) When

$$\hat{\psi} = 
    \begin{cases}
            c, &         0< x < 1\\
            0, &         x > 1
    \end{cases}$$

show the solution can be written as,

$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2}\left[(x + ct + 1)H(x + ct + 1) - (x + ct - 1)H(x + ct - 1) - (x - ct + 1)H(x - ct + 1)  + (x - ct + 1)H(x - ct + 1) \right]$$

Where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside function.

Edit: I would just appreciate a hint, and a discussion about what I should be looking for in this problem. The even extension of $\hat{\psi}$ looks like the Top Hat Function which I know has relation to delta functions, and the Heaviside function is the integral of the Dirac delta function, so perhaps this holds some significance. Regardless, I am unable to achieve what the question asks and would appreciate someone's help. This is not for an assignment. I am currently preparing for exams and this is a question I was unable to do and so I am seeking guidance.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thankyou.

Comment: I believe you should investigate a little more yourself before asking.

Comment: @Joce Investigate using what? I have not come here asking for someone to do my homework for me. I am in the process of preparing for exams, and cannot see how the Heaviside function appears in the form described, apart from perhaps consdering that the Heaviside function is the integral of the Dirac Delta function, and that the even extension of $\hat{\psi}$ looks like the Top Hat function which when limits are involved can be a Delta Function.
I would much rather someone open a dialogue with me and give me some guidance. I wouldn't have posted if I hadn't spent substantial time on the problem.

Comment: These questions didn't appear clearly to me before your edit. You can rewrite $\hat{\psi}$ in terms of one Heaviside, and its even extension in terms of two. Then you'll be nearly done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Yes, even extension is appropriate for $u_x=0$ boundary condition.

b) The first step is to express the extension of $\hat \psi$ in terms of Heaviside function $H$. This does not do much mathematically, other than introduce convenient notation. In your case, the extended function 
$$\Psi(x ) = \begin{cases} c ,\quad & -1<x<1 \\ 0,\quad & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
can be written as 
$$\Psi(x ) = cH(x+1) -cH(x-1)$$
because it jumps up by $c$ at $x=-1$ (as $cH(x+1)$ does), and then down by $c$ at $x=1$ (as $-cH(x-1)$ does).

In general, a piecewise constant function that jumps by amount $\delta_j$ at point $x_j$ would be written as $\sum_j \delta_j H(x-x_j)$.

Then you need antiderivative of $\Psi$, for the purpose of integration in d'Alembert's formula. Note that $xH(x)$  is an antiderivative of $H(x)$, and more generally $(x-a)H(x-a)$ is an antiderivative of $H(x-a)$. So,
$$F(x) = c(x+1)H(x+1) -c(x-1)H(x-1)$$
as an antiderivative of $\Psi$. Finally, plug into d'Alembert's formula: 
$$
u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2c}\int_{x - ct}^{x + ct}\psi(s)\,ds 
=\frac{1}{2c}(F(x+ct)-F(x-ct))
$$
and you'll get the answer as in your post.