# Could anybody help solve the following partial differential equation, and provide a graph of the solution at $t=\frac{1}{2}, 1, 2$?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations

The problem is as follows:

Use D'Alembert's solution to solve for $u(x,t)$ given that
\begin{equation}
u_{tt}=u_{xx},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u(x,0)=0,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u_t(x,0)=\begin{cases}
1,&-1<x<1,\\
0,&\mathrm{otherwise},\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $-\infty<x<\infty$ and $0<t<\infty$.

My attempt at a solution:

We recall that D'Alembert's solution is as follows
\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\left[f(x+ct)+f(x-ct)\right]+\frac{1}{2c}\int^{x+ct}_{x-ct}g(x')dx'.
\end{equation}
From the initial conditions given in the question $f(x+ct)$ and $f(x-ct)$ vanish. As a result, we are left with a solution with a left-moving and right-moving wave
\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\int^{x+t}_{x-t}B(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}[R(x+t)-R(x-t)],
\end{equation}
where $B(x)$ and $R(x)$ are the box and ramp function, respectively. These functions are defined as follows
\begin{equation}
B(x)=\begin{cases}
    1,&-1<x<1,\\
    0,&\mathrm{otherwise},\\
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    R(x)=\begin{cases}
    x,&-1<x<1,\\
    -1,&x<-1,\\
    1,&x>1.\\
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
However, despite my attempt, I'm not sure if my solution is correct. Additionally, I am unsure as to how one should graph the solution. Could somebody offer any insight as to how this problem should be solved?

Comment: Hi there, please type the important mathematical content with Mathjax. This helps users with slow connections, poor eyesight, or maybe imgur is blocked in their workplace. You can get started [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), a more complete reference can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Something is obviously wrong with your solution. It doesn't make sense that $u=0$ for $|x| \ge 1$ when $t>0$, since the wave will spread outwards. (Do you know about the concept **domain of influence**?)

Comment: @HansLundmark, I am aware that my solution is incorrect, as I am unsure as to how to solve the following problem. I am unsure of what you are referring to, could you possibly type/write up a solution, so I can understand what you mean. Thank you for looking at the problem.

Comment: Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767342/dalemberts-solution-and-heaviside-function